# Get Matched Class in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following div in my HTML:

```html
<div id = "foo" class = "bar barbar foobar"></div>
```

and I'm using this code to select the div:

```js
$('.foo, .barfoo')
```

Is it possible to only get the matched class of the selected class? So for instance, if I have a `barfoo` class in my HTML, it would return the `barfoo` class, or it would return `foo` class if it had the `foo` class.

Comment: So you want to figure out which part of the selector matched, is that right?

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's a better way to put it, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the selector by commas, and `.find` which one `.matches` the element you're iterating over:

```js
const selector = '.foo, .barfoo';
const selectors = selector.split(', ');
$(selector).each(function() {
  console.log(
    selectors.find(sel => this.matches(sel))
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "foo" class = "bar barbar barfoo"></div>
<div class = "foo"></div>
```

If you want to remove the `.` part, `.slice` it off:

```js
const selector = '.foo, .barfoo';
const selectors = selector.split(', ');
$(selector).each(function() {
  console.log(
    selectors.find(sel => this.matches(sel)).slice(1)
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "foo" class = "bar barbar barfoo"></div>
<div class = "foo"></div>
```

Comment: Extremely unlikely, unless you have tens of thousands of elements you're doing this to every second, or something like that. If you have performance issues, they're almost certainly mainly due to other parts of your script.